# Creating really bold text with css

Tags: css

Is there any way to make my font bolder then my examples below? I have tried increasing `font-weight` from 900 to 1500 but I don't see any difference.

```
#step-1 div {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `font-weight: 900` is the maximum. You could use another font.

Comment: Thank you. My wire frames are created with Arial and the text looks much bolder. Strange.

Answer (score 6):

Use `text-shadow` to make it look bolder.

```css
.really-bold {
  text-shadow: -1px 0, 0 1px, 1px 0, 0 -1px, -1px -1px, 1px 1px, -1px 1px, 1px -1px;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.really-bold {
  text-shadow: -1px 0, 0 1px, 1px 0, 0 -1px, -1px -1px, 1px 1px, -1px 1px, 1px -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">SAMPLE TEXT</div>
<div class="really-bold">SAMPLE TEXT</div>
```

Comment: +1, but this won't work with dirty ones from Redmond (called IE) before version 10... just if somebody cares. ;-)

Comment: This is really clever. I tried text-shadows, but couldn't figure out how to spread it. using 8 works ...

Comment: If you're using a dynamic font-size, I find using `ex` unit works (`--weight: 0.025ex;`), better than `(r)em`.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr Thanks for suggesting not to specify color in your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35848767), but the use of CSS variables should be one's own preference and isn't integral to this answer and should not be edited as such. Besides, this trick involves placing multiple text shadows around a piece of text and the offset isn't really adjustable as the illusion breaks when its offset is increased. In the future, stick to using comments if you have something to add. Suggested edits should only be used when you need to correct something in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use only **one** of the following properties:

```
font-weight: normal
font-weight: bold

font-weight: lighter
font-weight: bolder

font-weight: 100
font-weight: 200
font-weight: 300
font-weight: 400
font-weight: 500
font-weight: 600
font-weight: 700
font-weight: 800
font-weight: 900

font-weight: inherit
```

Comment: Very few of these are supported by Chrome as of 2023. Certainly not 900.

Comment: @DavidSpector These are **all** supported by [all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#browser_compatibility) and has been for a while. With that being said, certain (many) "fonts" may not support all the weights.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `font-weight` means asking for a *typeface* of the given weight. It is not expected to make browsers artificially bold characters, though such things *may* happen for `font-weight: bold`, when a bold typeface is not available.

So the way to use something bolder than bold is to find a font with a suitable typeface and use it. This in effect means that you would need to use a downloadable font (web font, `@font-face`), since fonts commonly available in people’s computers do not have such typefaces.

For Arial in particular, there’s Arial Black, but many browsers treat it as a separate font family rather than a heavy typeface of the Arial family. Therefore, the best odds of getting it is to declare `font-family: Arial Black; font-weight: normal`.

Using `text-shadow` with the color of the text or other tricks never makes the font any bolder; it just creates an illusion of boldness, and it is typographically a no-no.

Comment: This is bad news. A strange limitation of Web typography. Most drawing programs (like Inkscape) can render the thickness of text just about as thick as you like, using SVG.